# How to disconnect a light path node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface, node-editor

My question seems obvious but I did not understand why I could not disconnect the path light node for other node. I have never had a problem with other node.
To disconnect any node ,I press the left button of the mouse on the output extremity of the link and I drag.

Exemples:

[image: Light Falloff node]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That should work for any node.. But another way is to hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> and drag <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>, "cutting" the node link(s) (aka noodles):

[image]

Comment: @startingBlender Though it's really odd that dragging the end connected to the light falloff node it didn't work..